# Flutter: How to call a method in different class

Tags: flutter, webview

I have a Tab bar in which one of the tabs is web-view. I want to change the web-view url from parent class when the first tab is clicked. How to do that? I am kinda stuck.

How can i change the URL of webview when the bottom tabbar is clicked? Coz i want to change the url when the first tab is clicked to a different URL.

**Parent class with tabs**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> implements HomeTabListener {
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool isLoggedIn = false;
  int bottomNaviIndex = 0;

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  double xPosition = 200;
  double yPosition = 300;
  bool isBackToNormal = true;
  List pages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pages = [
      WebMain(),
      // MailMain(),
      MessageMain(),
      FolderMain(),
      Container(),
    ];
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**Child Class with Webview**

```
class WebMain extends StatefulWidget {
  WebMain({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WebMainState createState() => _WebMainState();
}

class _WebMainState extends State<WebMain> {
  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  InAppWebViewController webViewController;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;

  ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print("Webmain called");
}
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Webmain build");
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: setupURL(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Container();
                  }
                  print(snapshot.data);
                  return SafeArea(
                      child: InAppWebView(
                          key: webViewKey,
                          // contextMenu: contextMenu,
                          initialUrl: snapshot.data,
                          // initialFile: "assets/index.html",
                          onWebViewCreated:
                              (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                            // webViewController = controller;
                          },
                          onDownloadStart: (controller, url) async {
                            String query =
                                "SELECT * FROM task WHERE url='" + url + "'";
                            var tasks =
                                await FlutterDownloader.loadTasksWithRawQuery(
                                    query: query);
                            if (tasks != null && tasks.length != 0) {
                              var path =
                                  '${tasks[0].savedDir.replaceAll('(null)', '')}${Platform.isAndroid ? "/" : ""}${tasks[0].filename}';
                              OpenFile.open(path);

                              return;
                            }
                            print("onDownloadStart $url");
                            showToast("Downloading file...", 2);
                            final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                              url: url,
                              savedDir: (Platform.isAndroid
                                      ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                      : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory())
                                  .path,
                              showNotification: true,
                              // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
                              openFileFromNotification:
                                  true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
                            );
                          },
                          shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller,
                              shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest) async {
                            var url = shouldOverrideUrlLoadingRequest.url;
                            var uri = Uri.parse(url);

                            print("shouldOverrideUrlLoading $url");

                            if (url.contains("/download/fileAttachments") ||
                                ((url.contains("/download/formMessageChat"))
                                // && url.endsWith(".txt.?attachment=true")
                                )) {
                              String query =
                                  "SELECT * FROM task WHERE url='" + url + "'";
                              var tasks =
                                  await FlutterDownloader.loadTasksWithRawQuery(
                                      query: query);
                              if (tasks != null && tasks.length != 0) {
                                print("onDownloadStart hurrrrrrr???");
                                var path =
                                    '${tasks[0].savedDir.replaceAll('(null)', '')}${Platform.isAndroid ? "/" : ""}${tasks[0].filename}';
                                OpenFile.open(path);

                                return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.CANCEL;
                              }

                              showToast("Downloading file...", 2);
                              print("onDownloadStart $url");
                              final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                                url: url,
                                savedDir: (Platform.isAndroid
                                        ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory())
                                    .path,
                                showNotification: true,
                                // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
                                openFileFromNotification:
                                    true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
                              );

                              return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.CANCEL;
                            }

                            return ShouldOverrideUrlLoadingAction.ALLOW;
                          },
                          initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                                javaScriptEnabled: true,
                                debuggingEnabled: true,
                                useOnDownloadStart: true,
                                useOnLoadResource: true,
                                javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
                                useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
                              ),
                              android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(),
                              ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
                                allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
                                // limitsNavigationsToAppBoundDomains: true // adds Service Worker API on iOS 14.0+
                              ))));
                })),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would recommend to use a state managment like Provider or Bloc. With these state management you can change your value from anywhere in the app and it will refresh the update value in every widget that is using the value.

Comment: @Ayad How can i achieve that? I am new to flutter I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I would recommend you to use Provider if you are new. You need to create a class that will extend ChangeNotifier and create the variable url in that class. You can find the documentation on how to use Provider in https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: @Ayad Thanks. I was able to do using Provider class. I am facing another issue but thats another one related to push notification. If you can spare few mins i share the link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67208565/how-to-configure-firebase-messaging-to-not-show-push-notification-for-some-type